# How to use one on one grep between 2 columns of a data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe X with 2 columns named "pattern" and "text" in R.
I want to search each pattern within the corresponding text.

For this I am using the grepl command. However, grepl is working fine only in the following scenario where it finds one pattern and tests against each row of the dataframe column:

```
grepl("findthis",X$text)
```

However, when I do the following, it only checks the first record of the first column one by one against all records of the second column.

```
grepl(X$pattern,X$text)
```

I am looking for a function which would take the first record of X$pattern and check it in the first record of X$text, then take the 2nd record of X$pattern and check it in the second record of X$test.

### Is this possible through some library function?

Edit: The solution given by @akrun works as per my requirement.However, I am using a series of grepl commands in a nested ifelse. Simply put it is something like the code below (but with more nesting):

```
X$result = ifelse(grepl(X$pattern,X$text),1,ifelse(grepl("abc",X$email),2,3)
```

How do I solve for this?

Comment: If @akrun gives you a solution and it's not what you need, you should seek deep in yourself for reasons. In this case it appears to me that your question lacks sufficient detail to support further efforts. Put in some real data, preferably using `dput(.)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is `Map/mapply`

```
 unname(mapply(grepl, X$pattern, X$text))
 #[1]  TRUE FALSE
```

#### data

```
X <- data.frame(text = c("find this text", "Something else"),
     pattern = c("find this", "find that"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanx a lot ..this works as per my requirement. However, I am using a series of similar grepl commands in a nested ifelse. So, it is something like

    `X$result = ifelse(grepl(X$pattern,X$text),1,ifelse(grepl("abc",X$email),2,3)`